# Работа php mysql и html

Tags: php, html, mysql

При запуске данного кода на странице ничего не выводится даже если добавляю простой html. Подскажите в чем проблема, работаю на localhost, запрос БД правильный в СУБД дает адекватные значения, инфо в БД тоже присутствует.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
     <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $server = 'localhost';
            $user = 'root';
            $pass = '';
            $db_name = 'task_1';

            $link = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db_name);

            if ($link === false) 
                die ("Problem with connection: " . mysqli_connect_error());
            else
                echo "Connection succesful";


            $result = mysql_query('select customer.cus_name, sum(pay.p_value) 
                                    from customer
                                    inner join pay on customer.id_customer = pay.cut_id
                                    group by customer.cus_name');

            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>customer_name</th>
                    <th>summ pay</th>
                </tr>
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $row[0];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo $row[1];
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            </table>
 ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Посмотрите в браузере "исходный код страницы". 2. Посмотрите логи web-сервера, возможно там критические ошибки. 3. Пол логам веб-сервера убедитесь, что обращение реально шло к вашему скрипту

Comment: Ошибок нигде нет, в таблице вместо значения ячейки выводится текст ячейки

Answer (score 1):

Забываете рвать php теги, перед тем как пишете html код

```
<html lang="ru">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
    <body>
    <?php
         $server = 'localhost';
         $user = 'root';
         $pass = '';
         $db_name = 'task_1';

         $link = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db_name);

         if ($link === false)
              die ("Problem with connection: " . mysqli_connect_error());
          else
              echo "Connection succesful";

          $result = mysql_query('select customer.cus_name, sum(pay.p_value)
                                from customer
                                inner join pay on
                                customer.id_customer = pay.cut_id
                                group by customer.cus_name');
      ?>
      <table border="1">
          <tr>
                <th>customer_name</th>
                <th>summ pay</th>
          </tr>
      <?php
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              echo '<tr>';
              echo '<td>';
              echo $row[0];
              echo '</td>';
              echo '<td>';
              echo $row[1];
              echo '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';
          }
      ?>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сейчас уже на многих системах `<?` не работает, и мест где он работает все меньше и меньше ибо разработчики php его в новых версиях "осуждают". следует использовать `<?php`.

Comment: Спасибо, таблица появилась, но появилась проблема, в таблице вместо значений выводится текст кода

Comment: Проверьте у себя все кавычки и теги. В коде выше все должно быть в порядке

Comment: а если к примеру php цикл закрыть два раза   <?php
          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>  а здесь вывести табличку <? } ?>  так пойдёт ?

Comment: @LenovoID Пойдет, только в таких случаях, для лучшей читаемости,  следовало бы использовать не фигурные скобки, а конструкцию типа `<?php while(...): ?> <!-- some html code --> <?php endwhile; ?>`. Такой синтаксис работает и для `if`, `for`, `foreach`, `switch`.
Да, и, внутри таблички вам все равно придется выводить значения так `<?php echo $row[0] ?>`

Comment: да  я согласен ! но всё же удобнее - на само деле цикл получится

Answer (score 0):

Возможно стоит прописать эту конструкцию

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>customer_name</th>
                <th>summ pay</th>
            </tr>
```

хотя бы через echo, а также закрывающий

```
</table>
```

Comment: Начало выводить текст функций, после соединения с БД:
'; echo ''; echo 'customer_name'; echo 'summ pay'; echo ''; while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo ''; echo ''; echo $row[0]; echo ''; echo ''; echo $row[1]; echo ''; echo ''; } echo ''; ?> 
Без какого либо выполнения

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
     echo '<table border="1"><tr>
                <th>customer_name</th>
                <th>summ pay</th>
            </tr>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $row[0]. '</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row[1]. '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
?>
```